# Create a Php file with code

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is to make an installation file where the user enters the database, username, password, and host as a first step in a php system installation.

Also I want to create a page where user give his model page name and variable names ( $name,$email ) then automatically create a file with php code like

```
class Admin extends MyBase 
{
    private $name,$email;

    public function setName($v)
    {
        $this->name = $v;   
    }
    public function setEmail($v)
    {
        $this->email = $v;  
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name; 
    }
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;    
    }
        public function Insert()
    {
        $sql = "insert into
        admin(name,email) 
        values('".$this->ms($this->name)."','".$this->ms($this->email)."')";    
        return $this->MyCommand($sql);
    }
 }
```

with code format.

Comment: And what problem are you specifically facing?

Comment: i can create a file but not create with code format @fiddler

Comment: code format? I dont see any line of file creation in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I can do a example

```
<?php



if (isset($_POST["Submit"])) {



$string = '<?php 

$dbhost = "'. $_POST["dbhost"]. '";

$dbuname = "'. $_POST["dbuname"]. '";

$dbpass = "'. $_POST["dbpass"]. '";

$dbname = "'. $_POST["dbname"]. '";

$prefix = "'. $_POST["prefix"]. '";

$user_prefix = "'. $_POST["user_prefix"]. '";

$dbtype = "'. $_POST["dbtype"]. '";

?>';



$fp = fopen("config.php", "w");

fwrite($fp, $string);

fclose($fp);



}



?>

<form action="" method="post" name="install" id="install">

  <p>

    <input name="dbhost" type="text" id="dbhost" value=""> 

    DB Host

</p>

  <p>

    <input name="dbuname" type="text" id="dbuname"> 

    DB Username

</p>

  <p>

    <input name="dbpass" type="password" id="dbpass">

  DB Pass </p>

  <p>

    <input name="dbname" type="text" id="dbname">

  DB Name </p>

  <p>

    <input name="prefix" type="text" id="prefix">

  DB Prefix</p>

  <p>

    <input name="user_prefix" type="text" id="user_prefix">

  Userprefix</p>

  <p>

    <input name="dbtype" type="text" id="dbtype">

  DB Type </p>

  <p>

    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Install">

  </p>

</form>
```